# Truncate left-most TextView only when laying out two TextViews side-by-side

Tags: android, layout, textview

This is my first question here as I find myself stumped with (yet another) should-be-simple-but-isn't layout issue.  I am trying to layout two TextViews horizontally, say Title and Author, such that:

Title is left-aligned
Author is right-aligned
Author wraps content, expanding as necessary, and never truncates.
Title fills the rest of the space and ellipsizes at the end if necessary.

So we have something like:
| Short Title               A. Writer |
| This is a very long ti... Job Blogs |
| Another Title Whi... A. Longer-Name |

I can't figure out any combination of settings to achieve this.  I know the issue is that layouts are performed left-to-right and so the Title doesn't know how much space it has because the Author hasn't been rendered yet.  But at the same time, such an obvious layout MUST be achievable?

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be able to work this out with a RelativeLayout? Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/author_textview"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It's fairly straightforward. The most interesting part is that you have the right aligned author textview wrap its width, the left aligned title textview fill it, but add as a constraint that the latter should stay to the left of the former.

Comment: That's done the trick.  RelativeLayouts was what I was missing.  Haven't used these yet.  Thanks for your help.